# Are Sylow p-subgroups of prime order have trivial intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For example, $|G|=57=19\cdot3$

By Sylow's Theorem, $G$ has no. of Sylow 3-subgroup and Sylow 19-subgroup $n_3=19,n_{19}=1$.

Define those $19$ subgroups as $S_{3,k},1\leq k\leq19$ that have trivial intersection but can we say $$C_{19}\cap S_{3,k}=\{e\}$$?

If yes, more generally, are Sylow p-subgroups of prime order always have trivial intersection?

Comment: Hint: The intersection is never empty (it will always contain the identity). Also, use Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: They all have trivial intersection by Lagrange's Theorem!

Comment: Yes, precisely (when they have prime order as here. Otherwise they need not).

Comment: What does "$\,S_{3,k},\,1\le k\le 19\;$ " mean ?

Comment: @DonAntonio "Define those $19$ subgroups as $S_{3,k},1\leq k\leq19$" I would interpret that as $S_3$ meaning it's a Sylow $3$-subgroup, and the $_{,k}$ to be an indexing of those $19$ groups ($k$ ranging, obviously, from $1$ to $19$, inclusive). So $S_{3,1}$ is the first one and $S_{3,19}$ is the last one.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks...and great guessing powers! But then the question is completely trivial: two subgroups of coprime order have always trivial intersection...

Comment: @DonAntonio By Lagranges theorem, which is what the comments above conclude, yes. Note that the orders here are not coprime, though, so you need another argument.

Comment: @Arthur Seems to be I'm still lost: isn't $\;C_{19}\;$ a cyclic group of order $\;19\;$ (and thus a Sylow $\;19\,-$ subgroup of $\;G\;$ ) here? And then, since $\;S_{3,k}\;$ is a subgroup of order $\;3\;$ , then they have coprime order...what am I missing?

Comment: @DonAntonio You're right, I misread the question. For some reason I thought it was about the pairwise intersection of the $S_{3, k}$'s. Which is still trivial, by Lagrange's theorem, but coprimality is not the right argument to invoke.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $B$ be subgroups of $G$ with $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$. The subgroup $A \cap B$ is subgroup of $A$ so $|A \cap B|$ divides $|A|$, by Lagrange's Theorem. Likewise $|A \cap B|$ divides $|B|$.  Since $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=1$, we have that  $|A \cap B|=1$. Therefore $A\cap B =\{1\}$.

Now taking $A$ to be a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $B$ to be a Sylow $q$-subgroup yields the desired result because $\gcd(|A|,|B|)=\gcd(p^r,q^s)=1$